# AUTOEXEC Configuration for DOSBOX doesn't work (Works on Windows)

Tags: fedora, windows, autostart, freedos

I'm trying to configure the Autoexec section of Dosbox. I downloaded `DOSBOX for Windows` and I added these lines :

```
[autoexec]
# Lines in this section will be run at startup.
# You can put your MOUNT lines here.

MOUNT C C:\DOSGAMES\
C:
```

I saved and ran Dosbox.exe, it worked !

I'm doing the same thing for `Dosbox in Fedora 30`, configuring the file `dosbox-0.74.conf` located in `/usr/share/dosbox/translations/fr`.

But when I run it, it doesn't work. 
Here is a screenshot : 
http://image.noelshack.com/fichiers/2019/30/2/1563874333-dosboxconf.jpg

It worked for Windows...

---

**I tried to put these lines on each `dosbox-0.74.conf` located in each translation folder, but still not working.**
I think that the application doesn't run this configuration file, **it seems to be another file, but which one?** I've made a search of `dosbox` and these were the only files existing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `.dosbox` folder was hidden by design.

Each user have its own default config file in `~/.dosbox/dosbox.conf` . For root, go in `/root/` and do `Ctrl+H` , and hidden folders will appear.

You can choose other config files with the corresponding flag, so make sure to configure the right dosbox.conf file.

Comment: This is an old Unix convention. Many user-specific configuration files are located in each user's home directory (`/root/` for the root user). If they were visible, they would clutter up the home directory, so it became the norm to start the names of those files with a dot, and the `ls` command was programmed to hide such *dotfiles* by default. Whether good or bad, this is such an old convention that it will be very difficult to completely change it.

Comment: Oh, thanks for the explanation, I see now. Merci, mon ami belge !